# Delete two records without using in statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Am trying to delete two records by using below query in Oracle.

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID=1 AND EMP_ID=2;
```

I know we can delete two records by using EMP_ID IN(1,2) statements, but why we can't delete two records by using by using two different EMP_ID?

Comment: Your SQL is tying to delete a record that has an ID of 1 _and_ an ID of 2, which isn't going to match anything. You want to match records that have an ID of 1 _or_ an ID of 2.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID=1 OR EMP_ID=2;
```

Note that EMP_ID=1 `AND` EMP_ID=2 does not match any records and thats why you are getting confused. IN clause is very similar to OR thats why your query works with IN clause as it matches like EMP_ID=1 OR EMP_ID=2;

Comment: @user3301956:- You are welcome. And if my answer helped you then please accept it. The right tick mark. Turns green when clicked! As it may help others facing the same issue in future

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. Let me elaborate my question, I have EMPLOYEE table which contains 5 columns i.e EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_ADD,EMP_CITY and EMP_ADD. I want to delete two records at a time. If I use below query it will work as we expected.
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NAME='VITTHAL' AND EMP_NAME='MUGULI' ;

But when I try to delete two records at a time by using below query it does not work as we expected.

DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID=1 AND EMP_ID=2;

Why second scenario is not working?? 
I hope you understood my question.

Comment: @user3301956:- Your query is not working because with `AND` when you are trying to find two IDs at the same time then it will not get it. Since the ID cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time as my guess is that it is a primary key. For name it is not the case, if you will check then my guess is that there might be some other data as well having the same name and thats the reason why your query is working with names.

Answer (score 1):

Try an or statment :)

```
EMP_ID=1 OR EMP_ID=2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` conditition:

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID IN(1, 2);
```

Or use `OR` operator instead of `AND`:

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_ID=1 OR EMP_ID=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code like the following should suffice:

```
DELETE
FROM   employee 
WHERE  emp_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```